# Expected TCL: upvar vs namespace variable performance

Tags: namespaces, tcl, upvar

Is there an expected, by spec/implementation, difference between accessing namespace variables vs. upvar.
I have to use a call-back function. I cannot just pass an argument.Empirically, upvar wins. But is that expected, in all reasonable case?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes definitely. fully scoped reference is faster than `upvar` reference which is faster than `variable` reference.

To find-out, the command 'time' is your friend:

```
namespace eval toto {
    proc cb_upvar {varname} {
        upvar $varname var
        incr var
    }

    proc cb_scoped {varname} {
        incr $varname
    }

    proc cb_variable {varname} {
        variable $varname
        incr $varname
    }
}

proc benchmark {cmd} {
    set toto::totovar 1
    time $cmd 100
    puts -nonewline "[lindex $cmd 0] =>\t"
    puts [time $cmd 20000000]
}

puts [info tclversion]
benchmark {toto::cb_scoped ::toto::totovar}
benchmark {toto::cb_variable totovar}
benchmark {toto::cb_upvar totovar}
```

Output:

```
toto::cb_scoped =>    0.47478505 microseconds per iteration
toto::cb_variable =>  0.7644891 microseconds per iteration
toto::cb_upvar =>     0.6046395 microseconds per iteration
```

Rem: the huge number of iterations is required to get consistent result.

Comment: Empirically, that what I got, but I was wondering if this is a fluke, or expected.

Comment: It depends really on how many times you're using a variable in a procedure. If just once, fully scoped is fastest. The other two options (which are semantically different from each other in key ways) become much more useful once you use a variable multiple times. But using `time` to find the truth is _great_ advice.

Comment: @DonalFellows is correct about highlighting that the choice shouldn't be only about speed but take into account the usage in the procedure.

Comment: I am using the variable over and over again, as the procedure may be called millions of times.